# Why do I get 'unstable features are only available in nightly channel' when running rustfmt?

Tags: rust, rustfmt

I have just updated my Rust to rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)

In my .rustfmt.toml file

```ini
# Basic
hard_tabs = true
max_width = 100
use_small_heuristics = "Max"

# Imports
imports_granularity = "Crate"
reorder_imports = true

# Consistency
newline_style = "Unix"

# Misc
binop_separator = "Back"
chain_width = 80
match_arm_blocks = false
match_arm_leading_pipes = "Preserve"
match_block_trailing_comma = true
reorder_impl_items = false
spaces_around_ranges = false
trailing_comma = "Vertical"
trailing_semicolon = false
use_field_init_shorthand = true
```

To install rustfmt via Rust nightly toolchain

```bash
rustup toolchain add nightly && rustup component add rustfmt --toolchain nightly
```

I got `nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.65.0-nightly (015a824f2 2022-08-22)`

Then to run rustfmt to check my code format...

```bash
cargo +nightly fmt
cargo fmt --check
```

I got a bunch of warnings!

```
Warning: can't set `imports_granularity = Crate`, unstable features are only available in nightly channel.
Warning: can't set `reorder_impl_items = false`, unstable features are only available in nightly channel.
Warning: can't set `spaces_around_ranges = false`, unstable features are only available in nightly channel.
Warning: can't set `binop_separator = Back`, unstable features are only available in nightly channel.
Warning: can't set `match_arm_blocks = false`, unstable features are only available in nightly channel.
Warning: can't set `trailing_semicolon = false`, unstable features are only available in nightly channel.
Warning: can't set `trailing_comma = Vertical`, unstable features are only available in nightly channel.
```

how can I solve these warnings? what is missing in my rustfmt.toml ?

Comment: What happens if you use `cargo +nightly fmt --check`?

Comment: Wow. That gives me nothing... I think this is what I want! Thank you!

Comment: If you always want to use the nightly compiler for a specific directory, you can run `rustup override set nightly` in that directly to make the nightly compiler the default. Then you don't need to pass `+nightly` to every invocation of `cargo` anymore.

Comment: @SvenMarnach is there a way to make nightly the default only for `fmt`?

Comment: @Holloway I don't think so. You could create an alias for `cargo +nightly fmt` perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the nightly toolchain explicitly for each `cargo fmt` call:

```
cargo +nightly fmt --check
```

Comment: Can't this be a project level config somewhere?